# Mac text editor for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, text-editor

My text editor of choice for PHP work is Panic's Coda.  But for Ruby on Rails, its autocomplete feature is continuously in my way and ROR's standardization on 2 space tabs does not play well with Coda's settings.  I've been going back to TextMate for ROR work, but was wondering if there were better options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think it's worth to give it a try, in my opinion TextMate is the best but it's not free.

The integrated boundles work very well for Ruby and Ruby On Rails.

There are also boundles for Subversion/Git/etc. which can be very usefull in development.

Comment: As I indicated, I am already back using TextMate, which is the overwhelming favorite here.  I prefer the flexibility of a text editor over an IDE, so I think I will just stick with this. Coda has the convenience of integrated ftp and command line, but given the other frustrations, I think I prefer TextMate for Rails.

Answer (score 5):

I say [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), great!

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but here's a couple more options that are (currently) free and nice:

- [Kod](http://kodapp.com/)
- [Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com/)

Comment: Kod is 404. Chocolat is no longer free but has a trial.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Aptana RadRails](http://www.radrails.org), which is free and based on Eclipse (although it seems slightly more stable for pure RoR than Eclipse-with-RadRails-plugin. I've only used it on Windows, but it does seem to have a Mac download available.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Ruby on rails developers use TextMate, you can see a lot of in several screencast. But there are a lot of use of MacVim too.

In this twice editor, there are a lot of plugin to help you coding with rails.

In IDE, there are Netbeans too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Textmate](http://macromates.com/), it has nice bundles for Rails and offers a great interface. There's even a [peepcode episode](http://peepcode.com/products/textmate-for-rails-2) about it.

I wouldn't use an IDE for Rails, but if you really want to, both Netbean and Aptana are worth looking at.

Comment: @marcgg why not use an IDE for Rails?

Comment: @adnan Because you don't really need one. It's not like C# where, without intelisense, you're totally lost. After some time using radrails then netbeans I realized that I wasn't gaining time. A simple editor is enough

Answer (score 0):

I use textmate and I love it.
I recommend installing ProjectPlus plugin that adds svn and git support to textmate drawer ( http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/05/textmate-plug-in-projectplus ).

If you are searching for full IDE NetBeans looks very good:
(http://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Textmate and Command Line

I used Eclipse/Radrails for a year and it totally sucks.

Answer (score 0):

How about Komodo Edit! Its great. and Free!!

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

Its open source and has features as syntax coloring, method/code folding, background syntax checking and code auto-complete

Comment: Doesn't look free, but maybe i'm missing something.